# How to properly configure a reactive select element that uses a nested form group?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular6

I've got an Angular 6, Reactive Forms project that connects to an ASP.NET Web Api 2 / MS SQL Server 2017 back end. I am in the middle of wiring up the front end and have come across a situation I have not yet encountered and can't find examples of how to accomplish:

[Nested FormGroups](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#nested-formgroups) whose object is represented by a `select` element. What I have so far does not error and it seemingly selects the correct item in the drop down upon load. However, upon selection, it *only* updates one field and not the whole object.

I *think* I need to use `formGroupName="company"` to tell `registerOnChange()` what control to look for and then some form of `formControlName="..."`, but I don't understand how do so with the `select` or `option` elements to achieve what I'm looking for. I need a selection to update the entire object, both the id and name properties.

***[Click here to view the StackBlitz editor/demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kfzq2b)***

#### site-edit.component.html

```html
...
<form class="form-horizontal" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()" [formGroup]="siteForm">
  <fieldset>
    ...
    <div class="form-group" formGroupName="company">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="companyId">Company</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <select id="companyId" class="form-control" formControlName="company">
          <option *ngFor="let company of companies" [ngValue]="company.name">
            {{ company.name }}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

#### site-edit.component.ts

```js
siteForm: FormGroup;

// TODO: refactor to use http Company Service instead
companies: Company[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Company 1'},
  { id: 2, name: 'Company 2'},
  { id: 3, name: 'Company 3'}
];
site: Site;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
            private siteService: SiteService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.siteForm = this.fb.group({
    ...
    company: this.fb.group({
      id: null,
      name: ''
    }),
    ...
  });
}

getSite(id: number): void {
  this.siteService.getSite(id)
    .subscribe(site => this.onSiteRetrieved(site));
}

save(): void {
  if (this.siteForm.dirty && this.siteForm.valid) {
    // copy form values over the site object values
    const s = Object.assign({}, this.site, this.siteForm.value);

    // simulate call to save service
    console.log('Saved: ' + JSON.stringify(s));
  }
}

onSiteRetrieved(site: Site): void {
  // clear all the state flags (dirty, touched, etc.)
  if (this.siteForm) {
    this.siteForm.reset();
  }
  this.site = site;

  // update the data on the form
  this.siteForm.setValue({
    ...
    company: {
      id: this.site.company.id,
      name: this.site.company.name
    },
    ...
  });
}  

... more
```

Answer (score 1):

since there is a lot of code to wire, I believe this is what you need,

```
<select formControlName="id">
    <option *ngFor="let company of companies" [ngValue]="company.id">{{country.name}}</option>
  </select>
```

### Update

The above solution is correct, but you need to do some changes in your stackblitz, I fixed it for you please take a look [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4qibc)

1. [ngValue]="company.id"
2. formControlName="id"
3. in your ts code `this.siteForm.patchValue` instead of `setValue`

please pay attention company name wont be updated, if you need to change company name as well you have to subscribe to change event and change either your form or change `site` object and patch form again

Comment: That blows up with the error _Cannot find control with name: 'id'_. Even if you put `company.id` or `company` it bombs. I believe it needs the `formGroupName="company"` incorporated for the `registerOnChange(...)` to pick up the control.

Comment: I've taken the time to create a [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kfzq2b) and update my question with a bit more clarity after messing with it while isolated in StackBlitz.

Comment: I mean, I get that I can do either the `company.id` or `company.name` and technically, using `company.id` is all I need because the back end only updates the id.  It just feels wrong to be sending back an object to the server with mixed/incorrect data. Is that really how this is all supposed to work? Do you _really_ have to subscribe to the change event and do _more_ work? Why can't the selection just set the object as a whole vs just a single property? Forgive my ignorance, I am extremely new to Angular.

Comment: @CodeMaverick you don't need to send it back to your back-end, I mentioned it in case you are binding name to your html

Comment: Thanks for you help pointing me in the right direction (+1). I ended up solving it a more way complete way, as to what I was wanting it to do. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50726040/682480).

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it by following Angular's [SetControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor) Model-Driven Example where it uses object identity to select the option.

***[Click here to see StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vpsb8g)***

I removed `formGroupName="company"` off the wrapper div, used `formControlName="company"` on the `select` which is the entire object, and then used `[ngValue]="company"` on the `option` which is also the entire object.

See below :

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="companyId">Company</label>
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <select id="companyId" 
            class="form-control" 
            formControlName="company"
            [compareWith]="compareCompanies">
      <option *ngFor="let company of companies" [ngValue]="company">
        {{ company.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

The only changes I needed to make in the class were :

1. Remove the FormGroup assignment of `company: this.fb.group({ id:
   null, name: ''})` and replacing it with `company: null`.
2. Implement the `compareWith` function. *Needed because the default comparison uses object identity and different objects have different identities. You can override this method with your own implementation to determine uniqueness.*

See below :

```js
ngOnInit(): void {

  this.siteForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    company: null
  });

  ...

}

compareCompanies(c1: Company, c2: Company): boolean {
  return c1 && c2 ? c1.id === c2.id : c1 === c2;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I missed that from the angular material documentation!